# how to find if the song is playing in android

Tags: android

i use MediaPlayer in android and i am playing a song by start method and i have to find if the song is playing or not .  if playing the seek bar has to move. if not playing seek bar does not move. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying%28%29)?